# Dynamics CRM how to get list of all entities

Tags: c#, crm

Working with CRM 2013, how can I get a list of all entities in the CRM via the `connectionManager` class? I want to get *all* the entities for the current connection.

Comment: If you only need to have listed the entities present on the CRM, you can install the managed solution of the SDK. it should be in your SDK folder Tools\MetadataBrowser\  as a zip file.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547411.aspx

Also, yo can use the DumpEntityInfo App in  SampleCode\CS\Metadata\Entities (C#) that creates an xml file with all the entities currently in the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you for your comment and answer it work now, 
this is my function

```
public static EntityMetadata[] GetEntities ( IOrganizationService organizationService)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> attributesData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest metaDataRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();
    RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse metaDataResponse = new RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse();
    metaDataRequest.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity;

    // Execute the request.

    metaDataResponse = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)organizationService.Execute(metaDataRequest);

    var entities = metaDataResponse.EntityMetadata;

    return entities;
}
```

and i call my function in the windows app form like this:

```
var allEntities = CRMHelpers.GetEntities(service);
foreach (EntityMetadata Entity in allEntities)
{
    cbxEntity.Items.Add(Entity.LogicalName);
}
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating a new response object just to throw it away a few lines later? -- and what is the Dictionary object for? -- It doesn't look like it gets used anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for getting the entity metadata using code (C#) then we have inbuilt messages to get all entities and if required attribute level information as well. You can use the message "RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest". A sample code would be as follows to achieve the same.

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest retrieveAllEntityRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest
{
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true,
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes
};
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse retrieveAllEntityResponse = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(retrieveAllEntityRequest);
```

If you need to get a specific entity information then you may use the message "RetrieveEntityRequest". A sample for the same would be as follows,

```
RetrieveEntityRequest entityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes,
    LogicalName = entityName,
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};
RetrieveEntityResponse entityResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(entityRequest);
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Let us know if you need any more information on the same.

Comment: Thank your for your answer but when i call my function GetEntities VS has stopped working, this is my function :

Comment: public static EntityMetadata[] GetEntities ( IOrganizationService service) 
{RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest Request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest(); 
RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse Response = new RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse(); 
Request.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All;
Response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)service.Execute(Request); 
var entities =Response.EntityMetadata; return entities; }
and i call my function in the Load form like that  var allEntities = CRMHelpers.GetEntities(service);
foreach (EntityMetadata Entity in allEntities)
{cbxEntity.Items.Add(Entity.LogicalName);}

Comment: Is it stop working (like threw some exception?) or took some time. What I have noticed is getting the metadata normally takes some more time compared to normal fetching of data.