# Get ALL Entity Metadata in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm, fakexrmeasy

What I want to do is:

1. Retrieve all metadata from CRM.
2. Serialize that metadata and store it in a file.
3. At a later point, deserialize and eed that metadata to XrmFakeEasy for unit tests.

Steps 2 and 3 are done but I don't know how to accomplish step 1.
I've spent some time noodling around in the code and on Google but remain stumped.

We're using .Net so what I need is to read ALL the Entity Metadata (type: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityMetadata).

If anyone knows how to do this or can point me in the direction of the API (I haven't been able to find one) then please let me know.

P.S.
This case is for on-premise crm.

Comment: Is this on-premise or online?

Comment: What do you include in 'all metadata'? Is it entities and attributes? Or is it forms, workflows, plugins, view, dashboard, etc?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft it's on-prem

Comment: @SergeyTunnik I mean anything that the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityMetadata class can represent. I'm quite new to CRM so please forgive my ignorance (I'm working on it ;) 

I believe it's only entities (with their attributes etc) as that is what the documentation claims EntityMetadata represents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata?view=dynamics-general-ce-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right you need to use RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest request.
Here are more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29694213/2575544

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone that comes across this post here's

### My final solution

```
public static EntityMetadata[] GetMetadata(IOrganizationService crmService)
{
    var request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest
    {
        EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All
    };

    var response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse) crmService.Execute(request);
    return response.EntityMetadata;
}
```